# JFrame: String changing back to null after the value is changed in the constructor

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nullpointerexception, jframe

Just for clarification, i'm using JFrame Form in Netbeans.

Ok so basically i'm trying to change the value of a public global String (PictureName) using the constructor, because i'm trying to take another value from another class, but when I try to use it in my JLabel's code, it appears as null. Here is the code

```
public class ShowPage extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public javax.swing.JLabel Picture;
public String PictureName;

public ShowPage() {
    initComponents();

}

public ShowPage (String picName){
    PictureName = picName;
}


private void initComponents() {
Picture = new javax.swing.JLabel();
getContentPane().add(Picture);
    Picture.setBounds(20, 60, 300, 130);
    Picture.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/MiniProject/imagesMain/"+PictureName)));

pack();
}
```

Any ideas why PictureName remains null even after being changed (yes it was checked with a SOP) in the constructor?

This is the PSVM btw

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ShowPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ShowPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ShowPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ShowPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ShowPage().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have two separate constructors: One that takes no arguments and calls `initComponents()` and one that takes one argument and sets `PictureName` to the value in the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking the no-argument constructor instead of the one that takes the picture name as parameter. In `main` you should call:

```
public void run() {
    new ShowPage(pictureName).setVisible(true);
}
```

where `pictureName` is the variable that stores the file name of the picture.

The constructor also needs to call `initComponents()` just like the no-argument constructor does:

```
public ShowPage (String picName) {
    PictureName = picName;
    initComponents();
}
```

Comment: `initComponents` would also need to be added to the string argument constructor.

Comment: thank you so much. I've been stuck on this for days, asking my teacher and friends. I'm kinda new to JFrame. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

It throws a null event just because you **never initialize** your variable.

In your main, you call the without argument's constructor, which mean `PictureName` is never created.

You should try this

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new ShowPage("image.png").setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

After this, you should add in your `ShowPage(String picName)` constructor the method `initComponent()`, or it will never be called.

```
public ShowPage (String picName){
    PictureName = picName;
    this.initComponent();
}
```

---

Some other advices :

- Instead of write `javax.swing.JFrame`, just add an **import** on the top of your file :
  `import javax.swing.JFrame;` or even `import javax.swing.*;` to import all classes from the package (as `JLabel`)
- Be sure to write your variables with the first character in **lower case**, that's a basic rule of programmation : `PictureName` -> `pictureName`